# Force on a balls shell

Tags: pressure

Suppose we have a sphere with radius $r$ and the thickness of its shell is $l$.
The pressure outside is equal to pressure inside which is $p$.

Total force on the outside is: $F_o=pA_o=p4\pi (r+l)^2$

Total force on the inside is: $F_i=pA_i=p4\pi r^2$

so $F_o>F_i$ what happens then ??

Comment: Stress is exerted to the ball.

Comment: @lucas As a thought experiment imagine a large balloon with thick sides which is pulled open but not inflated or stretched. You would expect the pressure to be equal inside and outside the balloon. If stress is exerted you would expect the balloon to implode slightly and the pressure to re-equalise causing a run away effect. The end effect would be a balloon containing no air. Maybe something is wrong with the logic here but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: @OhAuth Sorry, I couldn't get your comment meaning.

Comment: @lucas It stress were exerted you would expect any non-rigid container with equalised internal and external pressure to implode (given my thought experiment). Meaning a. there is somthing wrong with my experiment (most likely) b. there is something else at play here and $F_0 \ngtr F_i$.

Comment: @OhAuth If the ball doesn't be rigid enough, then it will implode. If the ball is enough rigid, then it support the stress. If the thickness of the ball is big, and the ball isn't enough rigid, then it will be crumpled.

Comment: @lucas But in the case where the pressure could keep re-equalising (like the balloon) we could expect a run away effect where the balloon would keep imploding. However, we don't observe this.

Comment: @OhAuth 1. Balloon isn't a close sphere and we talk about a sphere ball in this question. 2. I don't know what is the "run away effect". May you explain it please?

Comment: @lucas 1. I know the balloon isn't a closed sphere, I am just curious as to the effects. Also a balloon would still have a smaller surface area on the inside than the outside, so $F_o>F_i$ would still hold. 2. A run away effect is where the outcome of a process makes the process continue, for example, the greenhouse effect in global warming (there are probably much better definitions).

Comment: @OhAuth Sorry, my English isn't good. I read all of your comments several times but, I couldn't understand what is your problem with my answer (third comment).

Comment: @lucas Thanks for your time lucas, I don't have a problem with your answer I was just questioning the phenomena further. I will leave this for now and maybe make my own official SE question in the future.

Comment: @OhAuth I hope I can help that time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sphere with no hole in the middle.  It is also under stress when placed in a pressurized fluid.  Your situation is no different.  The material of any object which is pressurized deforms very slightly until the stresses produced exactly balance the external pressures.  In essence, the material of the object is just like the fluid, and has its own internal "pressure", which is pretty much equal to the external pressure in most situations.

Nothing dramatic happens unless the substance of which the object is made becomes unstable under the higher pressures, e.g. graphite turning to diamond or ice melting under pressure.